# Is there one word/phrase for a village or city that is recently established?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, epithet-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase or even something like a idiom to describe a city or village or a colony that has been newly or freshly established and thus does not things like government or a well structured society.

Primary focus should be that it is established newly, so words like 'anarchy' don't work. 'Virgin' cannot be used to describe a society I guess.

For example

> Vandals roam in your _____ city so you pick up your gun and with help
>   of your friends you lock them inside your basement, one by one.

I have looked that thesaurus for new, but I find no word appealing.

Any connotation should work. 
A compound word will also work fine.

Comment: Fledgling would work if you just want to mean new.

Comment: ... Spot on; the answer.

Comment: I struggle to understand why *new* isn't suitable.  It is, after all, the adjective most closely related to the adverb *newly*.  And settlements, unlike baby birds, do not leave the nest when they grow up.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It is but I have used that word too many times already, It will make the passage very boring.

Comment: @JRodge01 It is perfect!

Comment: a person or organization that is immature, inexperienced, or underdeveloped : Fledgling @HighPerformanceMark